# No me funcionan los enlace de ancla de en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hosting, menu, elementor

Hola tengo un inconveniente con wordpress al colocar los enlaces de ancla hace unos dias si me funcionaban , sin embargo ahora solo me funcionan en el navegador Edge quisiera saber a que se debe ese error estoy trabajando con el plugin de Elementor y woocommerce
A continuación les adjunto el link de mi sitio web esperando me ayuden con este inconveniente muchas gracias de antemano
https://i-solutions.com.ec/wp/principal/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi como pueden ver este error me sale aunque no he tocado nada creo que por eso no me funciona alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo

Comment: Hola. No sabemos a qué te refieres y no se trata de inspeccionar tu sitio web buscando un problema que no has explicado con claridad. En la pregunta debe haber un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable del problema a partir del cual podemos ayudarte a encontrar una respuesta. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: por ejemplo si entras al sitio web en la seccion de contactenos no funciona el enlace de ancla sin embargo si lo pruebas en navegador de microsoft edge si funciona mi duda es porque solo en ese navegador funciona ante si funcionaba en todos los navegadores

Comment: Inspeccionando elementos si me sale un error ahora que lo dices

Comment: Te dice que `$scrollable` is not a function. Puede que estés intentando usar librerías que no tienes cargadas o algo así.

Comment: si puede ser aunque solo estoy usando bootstrap en una parte que hice el carrousel de la pagina

Comment: Pues busca por esa vía, debes resolver esos errores que tienes en consola.

Comment: Hola buenas días tengo el mismo inconveniente, como lo pudiste resolver?